# Standard ML Expand List

Tags: sml

> Directions
>
> Function `expand` that receives a list of any type and an integer
>   number `n`, and returns a list in which each item of input list is
>   replicated `n` times. For example, expand [1,2,3] 3 must be
>   evaluated to [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3].The type of the function must be ‘a
>   list→int→‘a list.

Here's my solution where I cheated around the requirements a bit by having two functions. What I am struggling with is resetting `n` to the original value when I move on to the next item in the list. I do so in my implementation by saving the original `n` value to `s` which is never changed. How do I go about removing the need for `s`?

```
fun duplicate([], n, s) = [] |
    duplicate(l, n, s) = 
    if n > 1 then hd l::duplicate(l, (n-1), s)
    else hd l::duplicate(tl l, s, s);

fun expand([], n) = [] |
    expand(l, n) = duplicate(l, n, n);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining helper functions isn't "cheating", it's good.
It's a bigger problem that you defined a function with the wrong type - the type of `expand` is more important to the exercise than the number of functions you end up with (note that the description says what the type "must be", but not that you're not allowed to define helper functions).

You're having problems because you're trying to "attack" the whole input list at once.
When you have a "do X with each element of a list" problem, the first thing to do is to think "write a function that does X with *one* thing and then `List.map` it".

If we had a function that could repeat something `k` times, we could apply that to each list element.

We could write `repeat: int * 'a -> 'a list`, but that needs both a number and a thing and is inconvenient to `map` anywhere.
It would be nice if we could "fix" the number dynamically and get a function `'a -> 'a list`.
Currying lets you do exactly that, if you give the parameters in a convenient order.

```
fun repeat 0 i = []
  | repeat n i = i :: repeat (n - 1) i;
```

Load and test:

```
val repeat = fn : int -> 'a -> 'a list
val it = () : unit
- repeat 3 4;
val it = [4,4,4] : int list
```

Looks good so far.
We can now write `repeat 4` and get a function that takes "something" and repeats that four times.

Let's use it:

```
- fun expand xs n = List.map (repeat n) xs;
val expand = fn : 'a list -> int -> 'a list list
```

The type doesn't look great. Let's see what we just created.

```
- expand [1,2,3] 3;
val it = [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]] : int list list
```

Almost correct - the list should be "flat".

Luckily, the [List structure](http://sml-family.org/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.list:TY:SPEC) has a function that helps: `concat: 'a list list -> 'a list`, which takes a list of lists and appends them together, so we can just pass the result along to that:

```
- fun expand xs n = List.concat (List.map (repeat n) xs);
val expand = fn : 'a list -> int -> 'a list
```

That looks better.

```
- expand [1,2,3] 3;
val it = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3] : int list
```

Comment: Good to know `concat`. Your high-order functions are really elegant. Mine is pretty rude XD

Answer (score 1):

> Here's my solution where I cheated around the requirements a bit by having two functions.

This is not a problem. Using `helper` function is good when writing standard ml. Particularly, the helper function here is tail recursion, which will optimize stack frame. Sometimes(not here) nested case for a pattern is an alternative, but the cost is more memory required because of no tail recursion.

> How do I go about removing the need for s?

I don't know why don't you like the extra `s`. But I do have a solution: use closure to save it implicitly.

compact style:

```
fun expand [] n =  []
    | expand (node::list) n =
      let   fun n_times f n x = if n = 0 then x else f (n_times f (n-1) x) 
      in    n_times (fn list => case list of node::list => node::[node]) n [node] @ expand list n end
```

More readable style:

```
fun expand [] n =  []
  | expand (node::list) n =
    let
        fun n_times f n x =
            if n = 0
            then x
            else f (n_times f (n-1) x)
    in
        n_times (fn list => case list of node::list => node::[node]) n [node]
        @
        expand list n
    end
```

This closure (`fn list => case list of node::list => node::[node]`) doesn't include extra `s`, but what it to do is help `n_times` to complete n times cons. I think this is what you want

BTW, the requirements `expand [1,2,3] 3` and `‘a list→int→‘a list` require you to use curry function instead of tuple/non-curry function(all arguments in standard ml is just one tuple) . So, the solution I give above uses curry function(`expand [] n` and `n_times f n x`) . You can also use one help function to convert non-curry function into curry function:

```
fun curry_helper f x y z = f (x, y, z)
```

Feel free to comment if somewhere you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses standard-library functions:

```
fun expand (xs, n) =
    List.concat (List.map (fn x => List.tabulate (n, fn _ => x)) xs)
```

And here is another:

```
fun expand (xs, n) =
    List.foldr (fn (x, acc) => List.tabulate (n, fn _ => x) @ acc) [] xs
```