# why function type is (’a -> ’b) * ’a list -> ’b list?

Tags: sml, smlnj

```
fun map (f,xs) =
 xs of
 [] => []
 | x::xs’ => (f x)::(map(f,xs’))

(’a -> ’b) * ’a list -> ’b list
```

In terms of f first, should f have different return type with arguement?

**If we apply f as double function(fn x=>2*x), its type is int->int**

So I can't understand **why ('a->'b)type in map function**

Also f x :: map(f,xs') , i think , **it should have 'a * 'a list.**
(and true::[1,2,3] is not acceptable as we know)

When we think about 1::[2,3], then 1 is int and [2,3] is int list
So I think it should be **('a -> 'b) * 'b list ->  not (’a -> ’b) * ’a list -> ’b list**

Comment: You can't make `true :: [1,2,3]`, but you can make `true :: map (fn x => x > 0, [1,2,3])`

Comment: Note that `’b` isn’t necessarily different from `’a`. They are type variables and may have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

> In terms of f first, should f have different return type with arguement?

Yes, it should. Please image: applying `map` to a list, what we want to do is turning every element into a list.

Here is an application: `expand [1,2,3] 3` ====> `[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]`. In this case, `a` is `int` while `b` is `int list`, do you see? They are different type.

You can find a more thorough explanation about this case in this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52739994/6949852)

---

> So I think it should be ('a -> 'b) * 'b list ->

That's not true. `('a -> 'b) * 'b list -> ????` Please tell me what's your last type of parameter. No matter what the last type is, it should always be `('a -> 'b) * 'a list ...` instead of `('a -> 'b) * 'b list ...`

---

- the type of `f`: `'a -> 'b`
- Assume the type of `xs`: `'x list`
- Then, the type of `x`: `'x`

Notice this expression: `(f x)`, which tells you `x` is `f`'s argument. So, type `'x` must equal to type `'a`, not `'b`.